# validating user against existing standart asp.net sql membership from windows application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a asp.net web application which uses standart sql membership provider. And I have a windows application that runs on the same machine with the web application.

I want to add a login control to my windows application and I want that login control to validate user credentials against existing asp.net sql membership system..

Is it possible?

Thank you...

Comment: What do you mean by _asp.net sql membership system_ ??

Comment: http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm

Comment: @Akram: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb

Comment: I've just found this piece of code that generates exact characters which asp.net standart hashing algorithm also produces.

http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/aspnet-membership-password-hashing-algorithm/

Now I just need to query the db and compare the values..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the security related data stored in the membership database. You can use this data to authenticate the windows forms users by execute some queries that compare the provided user's credentials with those ones in the database.

Refer to Using the [ASP.NET membership provider in a Windows forms application](http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm).